# How Facebook deals with text overflow?

Tags: html, css, facebook, text, overflow

I'm doing a comments system, but there's something that keeps bugging me. For an example when I post a comment that contains 300 symbols without spaces between them it will overflow the commentbox. Then I use

```
overflow:hidden
```

but that isn't exactly what I want. When I try the same experiment in Facebook comment, instead of overflowing and hiding, the whole string would be shown and will be somehow separated on new lines. How can I do this?

Comment: This is not an answer, but... you could take this opportunity to get to know your tools a bit better. With Chrome or Firebug (on Firefox) you can figure this kind of thing out, generally... also, if you can manage to save a copy of the page and still have the thing working (doubtful due to the Ajax), you could break things in an attempt to figure out what makes it tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably using [`word-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap).

As you can see from the link, it is supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your textarea tag

```
<textarea wrap="soft">
```

or this..

```
<textarea wrap="hard">
```

or you can use css to do it

```
textarea {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```